# How do I make a process modify a list passed to it in python?

Tags: python

I have some code that will download some json from an api. I have to go through many pages and requests.get is very slow so I'm trying to use multiprocessing to speed things up. Here is my code:

```
def worker(mod, offset, totalpages, arr):
    stuff = []
    for i in range(offset, totalpages, mod):
        data = requests.get("https://api.website.net?" + "page=" + str(i)).json()
        try:
            stuff += data["list"]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        print(str(i + 1) + " pages downloaded")
    for x in stuff:
        arr.append(x)
def getdata(threads):
    totalPages = requests.get("https://api.website.net?page=0").json()["totalPages"]
    proccesses = []
    items = []
    for i in range(threads):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(threads, i, totalPages, items))
        p.start()
        proccesses.append(p)
    for p in proccesses:
        p.join()
    print(items)
getdata(4)
```

This ends up printing an empty array, even though I'm using append which should change the referenced list. Is there any way I can change my code so that worker modifies the array that is passed to it instead of doing nothing?

edit: I figured it out, I have to use multiprocessing.Manager() to create a list that all the threads can access.

Comment: seems to be your code may be simplified to make us understand it faster and easier

Comment: Have you tried printing `arr` inside the loop `for x in stuff` before the line `arr.append(x)`?

Comment: I have tried printing arr inside the loop for x in stuff, and it prints only the data that was obtained inside that thread. The separate threads all seems to have their own distinct version of arr, and I can't seem to get them to all access the same variable.

Comment: If the remote server is slow, you are congesting it by adding parallelism. If your network is slow, you are congesting *that.*

Answer (score 0):

use `multiprocessing.Manager()` to create a `list` that all threads can access